# Is there any method in DASK for creating parallelism while counting distinct values from a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, dask

I have successfully extracted the  count of a specific word from a dataset but, it is taking too much time. I am new to parallel programming.
How can I create parallelism in the following code:

```
df = dd.read_csv('crime.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
distinct_values = df.YEAR.unique().compute()
counter = len(distinct_values)

values_count = {}

for i in distinct_values:
    count = df[df.YEAR == i].YEAR.value_counts().compute()
    values_count.update(count)
list = []
for x, y in values_count.items():
    dict = {}
    for i in x, y:
        dict['name'] = x
        dict['value'] = y
    # print(dict)
    list.append(dict)
# print(list)

maximum = max(distinct_values)
mininmum = min(distinct_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a groupby aggregation like the following?

```
df.groupby("YEAR").count.compute()
```

Or, if you need to do this as many operations, you should at least use the `dask.compute` function with many inputs rather than call the `.compute` method many times.